# Rich text editor (WYSIWYG) for Custom Fields input

Tags: wordpress

I know about the "[More Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/)" plugin. The plugin seems to have all the functionnality a would need. The problem is that it's no longer supported and seems to be broken with the latest wordpress release.

Do you have any suggestion on another solution that would suit my need? What I really need is the Rich Text Editor (WYSIWYG) for custom fields input.

Thank you

Comment: Here is solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20276424/2165415 it is easy to add rich editor using that method.

Answer (score 4):

**More Fields** has indeed been abandoned. You might also be interested in a similar plugin called **Custom Field Template**. There's also quite popular plugin that enables you to add all sorts of custom fields to your content types (date, wysiwyg,...) - meet **Magic Fields**. Here's also [nice overview of different options](http://www.kevinleary.net/6-ways-to-create-custom-write-panels-in-wordpress/) if you want to make some research first.

And when everything fails you can always do it yourself by hacking functions.php. Of course - some PHP skills are required to do that ;) I'm quite new to WP but this is my way of doing it for now. It's a lot of "reinventing the wheel" but I also learn how WP works under the hood.

P.S. I would add more links but I'm victim of spam prevention mechanism :-/

Answer (score 2):

WordPress function to add the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor to any custom field of type - https://gist.github.com/1885364

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/
It has plugin for wordpress

Answer (score 1):

I can also recommend [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). It has all of the features of "More Fields" and some, including the Repeater ($25 multi-site license, but it's worth it) which, as it suggests, allows you to repeat blocks of custom fields and is really nice for things like rotating banners etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this question is a long time ago, but I just want to add an option for WYSIWGY field.

It's the plugin [Meta Box](https://metabox.io/) which allows you to create custom meta boxes and custom fields with simple code. You can define as many fields as you want, of course, the plugin supports WYSIWYG field. Each field has many options for you to customize.

TL;D: I'm the author of the plugin and I'm happy to help and support anyone.