# how to get a wysiwyg editor in custom field wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg

I want to set up a custom field in the admin section of WordPress so that a client can go in and edit the content of the custom field without having to hard-code things with HTML.

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493313/how-to-add-wysiwyg-editor-in-wordpress-meta-box), but I'm not sure if this is really applicable to my case.

Does anyone know a quick/easy way to do this?

For further clarifcation, I bring in custom fields to my page like this:

```
<div id="greybackground"> <div id="greycontainer">
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'greycallout',true) ?></div></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$settings = array( 'media_buttons' => false,'quicktags' => false );
$content = 'Optional Message For Your Friend here... ';                     
$editor_id = 'postcueeditor';
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id,$settings );
```

paste this code where you want editor to appear. `$_REQUEST['postcueeditor'];` will contain data posted by the editor.

Comment: hmm where does this go though?  The functions.php file?

Comment: in your <form> tag where you want your wysiga editor to appear !

Answer (score 1):

fyi check [this addon](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-taxonomy-field-add-on/) which will allow you to add taxonomies to custom fields. the addon will allow you to save custom field taxonomy back to post terms. since addon doesnt currently support adding new terms, i used selectize.js (similar to chosen and select2, but without the code bloat). selectize.js has autocomplete and the ability to add new options on the fly. now you can manage taxonomies from advanced custom fields.

Good Luck

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll check it out.  So happy I found this plugin, going to make it a lot easier on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Custom Content Type Manager plugin on nearly all my WordPress projects (http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) and it allows you to create custom fields with a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: hmm thanks but I already have the custom fields created the old fashioned way... what I want is for an editor to appear instead of the text area in wordpress to edit the fields.  Make sense?

Comment: I figured it out, there's a plugin "advanced custom fields" that is pretty great that does this.  You have to know what you're doing to set up the custom fields so that content appears on your page (text, image), but it does exactly what I need and an "editor" for clients